# What is the most efficient way of finding software development jobs online in Europe for someone currently residing in Asia?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, applications, job-description

I am a web developer based in the Philippines.

I have explored several job sites online and found some that I'm confidently qualified for, mostly in the UK, Germany and Austria. The problem is I am not sure if these jobs accept foreign workers with no work permit in their country.

I could apply for all of these jobs despite the uncertainty about the work permit, but I would rather divert my time and effort into finding the most effective way of filtering these job postings so that the only jobs I see are the ones that I have a real chance on, as a foreigner.

I tried expatica.com, a job site specifically for foreign workers, but even the jobs there have something like "Must be eligible to work in ______" at the bottom of the description.

Comment: This is going to get closed as opinion based, but consider focusing more on remote work versus must be eligible to work in X

Answer (score 2):

The whole *"Must be eligible to work in ______"* thing is extremely common to see on EU jobs, mainly because obtaining the work permit is an expensive, difficult and time consuming process for an employer to go through so very few are willing to do so except for exceptional candidates or for jobs which are very hard to fill.

Sadly for you candidates with web development skills are pretty plentiful in those areas (they certainly are in the UK) so there is very little incentive for a company to go through the hassle and expense unless you are somehow truly exceptional.

I'm not overly familiar with mainland Europe or Australia but certainly for the UK I doubt you'd qualify for an *Exceptional Talent* visa because (and I mean no disrespect here) that would require you to be *"internationally recognised as world leaders or possess potential world-leading talent in the fields of science and the arts"* and I'd be surprised if that was the case here so therefore you likely be looking at a *"Tier 2 General Visa*" and for a company to be able to successfully sponsor you for such a visa they would have to be able to demonstrate that they couldn't have reasonably filled the position with a UK/EU national.

As IanSoNotListening's comment says looking for remote work (as an external contractor) would likely be much more fruitful as it sidesteps the whole work permit aspect entirely. Obviously though this is only feasible if you aren't looking to immigrate.

If you have your heart set on immigrating to one of those countries then I would suggest contacting the country's embassy in your locale and discussing your eligibility with them.